# Simple Math riddle

Tags: mathematics

I'm a number. The **difference between me and my checksum is 36** and I am the **product of two adjacent numbers**. Which number am I?

I know it's pretty simple but one that just came to my mind right now =D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are

> $42$

Checksum

> $42 - 4 - 2 = 36$

Product

> $42 = 6 \times 7$

Method

> It suffices to check the first few numbers which are the product of adjacent integers as the number itself grows much faster than the checksum and will surpass $36$ early on.

Comment: Correct! Congrats =)

Comment: I would like to add that if the difference between a number and its checksum is 36 you can now that the number will be between 40 and 49 .